# Shortcut for value assignment

Tags: c#, variable-assignment, shortcut

I have a simple value assignment, that checks if the new value is empty or not:

```
string newVal;
string val = (newVal = Console.ReadLine()) != "" ? newVal : "Default";
```

Is there a shorter way for achieving the same result?

Comment: No, but you might want to think about not doing something so side-effect heavy.

Comment: Perhaps not shorter, but certainly simpler and IMHO much more comprehensible: `string val = Console.ReadLine(); if (val == "") val = "Default";`

Comment: This is not a C++ question, `Console.ReadLine` is a C# thing. @ouah

Comment: @delnan, this is probably the only sensible answer this question could get, so post it as such.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
string val = Console.ReadLine();
if (val == "") val = "Default";
```

Not only shorter, but also simpler and easier to comprehend.
If you can stand a bit more "clutter", it's probably better style to put the conditional block on its own line:

```
string val = Console.ReadLine();
if (val == "")
{
    val = "Default";
}
```

Comment: Completely personal preference, but I have always been fond of actually specifying `string.Empty` or using `string.IsNullOrEmpty(myValue)` or `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(myValue)` depending on the framework version.

Comment: @TyCobb, My target isn't to check, if a variable is empty or not. This was only an example. My target is to prevent writing the same variable name three times in a "simple" variable assignment.